# Probability of two sets of items containing common subset of items

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

I've recently been pondering about the following problem:

> Kyle and his best mate Chad head over to the game shop to purchase
>   some new games. After squabbling over which games to purchase, Kyle
>   and Chad eventually limit their options to ten games. Kyle and Chad
>   have individual orders of preference which are independent of each
>   other and which the other person does not have any information about.
>
> To ensure they choose a game as fairly as possible, they agree that
>   Kyle randomly removes five options from the list, and then Chad
>   randomly chooses a game from the remaining five. What is the
>   probability that the game which Chad chooses is not in the top three
>   of either person's list of preferences?

The obvious thing to me is that the probability that Kyle's top three are in the five he chose is just ${7\choose 2}/{10\choose 5}$. What I am unsure about is the probability that Chad's random choice is in his top three for a given sample of five. Is this a joint probability (in Chad's top three AND from Kyle's selection) or a conditional one (in Chad's top three GIVEN Kyle's selection)? How do I account for the intersection of their preferences?

More generally, for two identical sets of $n$ items, if we select $m$ items out randomly from each set, how do we calculate the probability that the $m$-element subsets share $k$ elements in common? Is there a well-known distribution for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The general problem you stated can be rephrased as:

"If a bag contains $n$ balls of which exactly $m$ are black and $m$ balls are drawn without replacement then what is the probability that exactly $k$ of the drawn balls are black?"

With hypergeometric distribution we find that this probability is:$$\frac{\binom{m}{k}\binom{n-m}{m-k}}{\binom{n}{m}}$$

Observe that this can be looked at as $2$ random selections. Start with balls that are e.g. all white. Firstly $m$ balls in the bag are selected to be colored black and secondly $m$ balls are selected from the bag.

Comment: Hi, will I need to square the hypergeometric probability/multiply by n choose m?

Comment: Not if you are talking about the general problem that whas mentioned in the last paragraph of your question. The probability that two randomly chosen $m$-sets (subsets of the same $n$-set) share $k$ elements is mentioned in my answer. Are you talking about something else?

Comment: yeah, for the second bit. I get that choosing k black balls and m-k white balls from n total is hypergeometric but I don’t understand why the comparison with the second subset does not affect the probability. You mention at the end that m balls are selected to be coloured black, why is there no need to multiply by nCm? Why is there also no need to square the probability to account for the drawing of the second set?

Comment: Because - if it comes the question: "how many black balls will be selected?" - it is not relevant at all how the coloring of these balls took place. The only thing that matters then is: "how many black balls are there among the $n$ balls?". Well, $m$ as we know.